# How to disable button until good validation in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

How can I disable button until good textbox validation?
I have done some stuff but I don't know how to hide button until good validation in the right way with using MVVM pattern.
I am still learning this MVVM pattern.
Here are my fragments of code:

ValidationRule Class:

```
public class NotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())
            ? new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required")
            : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<TextBox
Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextFieldTextBox}"
AcceptsReturn="True"
TextWrapping="Wrap"
materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Content"
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsChecked, 
ElementName=MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBoxEnabledComboBox}" 
MaxLength="1000" materialDesign:ValidationAssist.UsePopup="True">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Task.Content" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <domain:NotEmptyValidationRule
                     ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ICommand _submitCommand;
public ICommand SubmitCommand
{
   get
   {
       if (_submitCommand == null)
       {
          _submitCommand = new RelayCommand(SubmitExecute, anSubmitExecute, false);
       }
       return _submitCommand;
    }
}

private void SubmitExecute(object parameter)
{
     Task.Id++;
     Tasks.Add(Task);
}

private bool CanSubmitExecute(object parameter)
{
     // What can I do to prevent to show this button when validation 
     // failed
     return true;
}
```

Comment: You should implement the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interface in your `Task` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface in your `Task` class, or implement it in your view model class and wrap the databound `Task.Content` property, e.g.:

```
private RelayCommand _submitCommand;
public ICommand SubmitCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_submitCommand == null)
        {
            _submitCommand = new RelayCommand(SubmitExecute, CanSubmitExecute, false);
        }
        return _submitCommand;
    }
}

private void SubmitExecute(object parameter)
{
    Task.Id++;
    Tasks.Add(Task);
}

public string Content
{
    get { return Task.Content; }
    set
    {
        Task.Content = value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Task.Content))
            _validationErrors[nameof(Content)] = "Field is required";
        else
            _validationErrors.Remove(nameof(Content));
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(nameof(Content)));
        _submitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}

private bool CanSubmitExecute(object parameter)
{
    return HasErrors;
}

#region INotifyDataErrorInfo
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
        || !_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        return null;

    return new string[1] { _validationErrors[propertyName] };
}

public bool HasErrors
{
    get { return _validationErrors.Count > 0; }
}
#endregion
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
```

You should not use a validation rule. They are not MVVM friendly. Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) blog post for more information.

You also need to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event of the `ICommand`. How to do this depends on the implementation. Most implementations have a method called something like  `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` or similar.

[WPF 4.5: Validating Data in Using the INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx)

Comment: I use this construct a lot and it works quite well for me.